# Populating Text Area with return from button callback function in Streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

Refer the image below:

[image]

I have the below user process flow / goal:

- Select a file using "Browse Files"
- Press "Fetch"
- This triggers the callback function of the 'Fetch' button
- The call back function returns a string output
- Write the string output to the text box (replace the "Select.")

I have the below code:

```
import streamlit as st
import os
import openai
from io import StringIO

from main import get_sql_response

@st.cache
def fetch_response(query_text):
    ## Get the API key  
    openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    ## Get the API response 
    response = get_sql_response(openai.api_key, query_text)
    print(response.choices[0]['text'])
    #st.caption(response.choices[0]['text'])
    st.text_area(label='The Query',key='qres', value=response.choices[0]['text'])
    return (response)

query_text = ""

st.markdown('## Sage Version  **V0.1**')

st.markdown("#### Query File ")

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader(" ", type='txt', accept_multiple_files=False, label_visibility="visible")

if uploaded_file is not None:
    # To read file as bytes:
    query_text = StringIO(uploaded_file.getvalue().decode("utf-8"))
    #st.write(query_text)

res = st.button("Fetch", on_click=fetch_response, args=(query_text))
qres = st.text_area(label='The Query',key='qres', placeholder="SELECT...")
```

I get the callback reult written to a new text box:
[image: call back result written]

And I also get the below error:

### [image: Duplicate Id error]

How do I write the callback function result to the same text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `st.text_area` with same key values, that caused the error. Change one of the key values of one the `st.text_area`. Every key **must** be **unique**.

```py
# make one of the key values here unique
st.text_area(label='The Query',key='qres', value=response.choices[0]['text'])
qres = st.text_area(label='The Query',key='qresvar', placeholder="SELECT...")
```